# Flutter reducir el tamaño de un icono dentro de un inputdecoration

Tags: flutter

El width no funciona , no lo reduce mas y nose que hacer para que no se me vea el icono tan garnde dentro de la caja , es un icono llamado desde la carpeta assets nose si tiene algo que ver pero por mucho que reduzcas el width no se reduce mas . Un saludo.

```
 Widget renderEmailInput() {
      return Container( 

        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
        child: TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        style: TextStyle(
        color:Colors.white,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
        ),
        textAlign:TextAlign.left ,
        obscureText:true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder( 
            borderSide: BorderSide(color:Colors.transparent),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
              topRight: Radius.circular(10),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
              bottomLeft:  Radius.circular(10)
            )
          ),
          prefixIcon: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/user.png',width: 10), 
          hintText: 'e-mail', 
          filled: true,
          fillColor: const Color(0xff0494a4)
        ),
      ),
    ); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `prefixIcon` se está estirando a todo el espacio disponible que tiene porque no hay `constraints`, agrega un `Center` encima de esto.

```dart
  prefixIcon: SizedBox(
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                child: Center(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/user.png', width: 10),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Gracias diego ya puedo manejar el tamaño el problema es que aora el texto no me aparece, ya que el icono esta en el centro y sobreescribe al hintText que aora no se ve.

Comment: corregido, revisa mi código nuevamente, usa el width y height que creas conveniente en SizedBox

Comment: Ostras genial muchas gracias creo que me queda aprender muchos tipos de widget y lo que hacen ejeejjejeej